# Reactjs function "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom-events

I am trying to use an additional function on submit as I usually did but it shows it's not a function.

```js
confirmSubmission = () => { // This doesn't work either: confirmSubmission() {
    //doSomething();
}

onSubmission(survey, options) {
    this.confirmSubmission(); // here it says Uncaught error: confirmSubmission is not a function
}
```

The function I used:

```js
return (<MyCOmponent model={model} onComplete={this.onSubmission}/>);
```

Other code that I have within `onComplete` executes fine if `confirmSubmission` is not there.

I have a similar code with another function which works perfectly fine in the same component:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData(); // This works
}

loadData() {
    doSomething();
}
```

I am confused why it doesn't like the `confirmSubmission` call. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have forgotten to bind the `this` context to `onSubmission`

```
constructor(/*...*/) {
  //..
  this.onSubmission = this.onSubmission.bind(this)
}
```

or

```
return (<MyCOmponent model={model} onComplete={this.onSubmission.bind(this)}/>);
```

Comment: Indeed, I was looking to register the wrong function. I don't quote understand why then it works without registering onSubmission when the additional function is not called in there?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```js
onSubmission(survey, options)
```

with an arrow function, it's the famous "this" issue